# Quran 26:214 and Bukhari 4971

Tags: quran

In the Quran 26:214, we read:

> And warn your closest kindred.
>
> ~ [[Source]](https://quran.com/26/214)

But in Bukhari 4971, we read: (It is weird that sunnah.com has left out the later part)

> When the Verse:-- '**And warn your tribe of near kindred & the group of sincere among them**' (26.214) was revealed. Allah's Messenger () went out, and when he had ascended
> As-Safa mountain, he shouted, "O Sabahah!" The people said, "Who is
> that?" "Then they gathered around him, whereupon he said, "Do you see?
> If I inform you that cavalrymen are proceeding up the side of this
> mountain, will you believe me?" They said, "We have never heard you
> telling a lie." Then he said, "I am a plain warner to you of a coming
> severe punishment." Abu Lahab said, "May you perish! You gathered us
> only for this reason? " Then Abu Lahab went away. So the
> "Surat:--ul--LAHAB" 'Perish the hands of Abu Lahab!' (111.1) was
> revealed.
>
> ~ [[Source 1](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4971)] and [[Source 2](https://sunnah.com/muslim:208a)]

I can't find the reference but Ibn Abbas testified to the deletion of this part in the verse 26-214..

### So, the question is:

Where did the later part go? I know someone will say, this was abrogated or these are ahrufs etc & that is fine but I need authentic evidence from the **Salaf** whether this was abrogated or these are ahrufs.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Imam al-Nawawī (d. 671 AH) and Imam al-Qurṭubī (d. 676 AH) both stated that this was a revealed verse that was abrogated. See al-Nawawī, al-Minhāj sharḥ Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim bin Ḥajjāj (Cairo: Mu’assasat Qurtubah, 1994) 3:102 and al-Qurṭubī, al-Jāmiʿ li-aḥkām al-Qur’ān, ed. ʿAbd Allāh al-Turkī (Beirut: Mu’assasat al-Risalah, 2006), 16:83.

Al-Kirmānī (d. 796 AH) adds the possibility of it being tafsīr: See: Sharḥ al-Kirmānī ala Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī (Beirut: DKI, 1971), 9:211.

Sourced from: [Origins of Quranic Variants](https://yaqeeninstitute.org/ammar-khatib/the-origins-of-the-variant-readings-of-the-quran)

Comment: I need authentic evidence from the Salaf not from Nawawi or Ibn Hajar or Qurtubi... Nawawi said "It was abrogated" means "it was abrogated" ?? Where is the proof?

Comment: @Ghz they used logical deductions. It's quite obvious that it was. It seems that you are doubting the scribes despite there being a consensus from every sahaba from the time of Uthman that they collected every verse that was still operative.